# strapi - how to create collection type using migration script

Tags: migration, content-management-system, strapi

**Background**
I've create my first strapi project using `npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart`.

I am able to access the admin console
[image]

**Purpose**
As you can see there is only `User` collection type in my project, what I want to do is to create a migration script to create another collection type.
The reasons is that I want to have a single source of truth, so I don't want to create the collection type directly in the Admin Console

**What I've tried**

I've tried to ask chatGPT, which provides me below workaround - `npm run create-content-type`.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.11.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.11.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.11.1",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi",
    "create-content-type": "strapi generate:migration create_my_collection_type"
  },
```

Error shows

```
error: unknown command 'generate:migration'
```

I've also tried `strapi make:migration create_my_collection_type`, but it doesn't work as well. Also checked the official document and I can't find any useful resource for it.

Is it possible to do in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `strapi generate`, you will be prompted to select what you want to generate, just select `content-type`. If you don't have strapi locally add a script `"strapi:generate": "strapi generate"`